# Different Types of Waves

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions, big-list, periodic-functions

I am making a basic 2D rigid body simulator as a hobby. It involves springs. Naturally, I need to render them. Rigid body simulators, such as [Algodoo](http://www.algodoo.com/), render them simply like this
[image]

Another (more common) helical representation
[image]

And many more...

So, to render these, I need some periodic function (with amplitude of $A$) which takes the number of turns $t$ (The number of turns is the same as the number of periods in the wave. E.g $\sin(x)$ contains $1$ turn in $[0,2\pi]$), and has the starting and end point $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ respectively. The end point and the starting point must be at "mean" position of the amplitude. (E.g $f(x)=0$ in $f(x)=\sin(x)$)
Any helical or triangle-wave like (or perhaps some other representation?) function will do. I don't know how to approach this.
I don't have access to built in functions for triangle waves, et cetera. Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Why did you accept ADG's answer within minutes, even though the question was misinterpreted? I immediately stopped working on the problem. I'd have shown you pretty cycloids.

Comment: He corrected it afterwards. The comment is older

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, so you won't show your pretty results because there is an answer already?

Comment: @abel: AvZ *accepted* a zigzag requiring the evaluation of two transcendental functions for every pixel (sic!). I got the impression that he is not interested in a good mathematical answer anymore.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, there may be others like me who may get something out of your answer. if you have an answer ready i don't see why it can't be posted. sometimes answers other than the answer accepted by op has greater number upvotes and also greater clarity.

Comment: @abel: You changed my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is to obtain the parametric representation of the projected spring $\gamma$ in your second figure, connecting the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$. Apart from the $y$-amplitude $A>0$ we can choose the number $2n+1$ of half-waves and a parameter $B>0$ which encapsulates the degree of selfintersection of $\gamma$. As a function of time, $\gamma$ is a superposition of a clockwise elliptical motion
$$t\mapsto\bigl(x_e(t),y_e(t)\bigr):=(A\sin t,-B\cos t)\qquad\bigl(0\leq t\leq(2n+1)\pi\bigr)$$
and a linear motion in $x$-direction, described by
$$t\mapsto x(t):=a+ bt\ ,$$
where $a$ and $b$ have to be chosen suitably. Therefore the parametric representation of $\gamma$ looks as follows:
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x(t)&:=a+bt-B\cos t \cr
y(t)&:=A\sin t\cr}\right.\qquad\bigl(0\leq t\leq (2n+1)\pi\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
The condition $x(0)=0$ gives $a=-B$, and
$$1=x\bigl((2n+1)\pi\bigr)=2B+(2n+1)\pi b$$
leads to
$$b={1-2B\over (2n+1)\pi}\ .$$
In this way the representation $(1)$ becomes
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x(t)&:=B(1-\cos t)+{1-2B\over (2n+1)\pi}\>t\cr
y(t)&:=A\sin t\cr}\right.\qquad\bigl(0\leq t\leq (2n+1)\pi\bigr)\ .$$
The reasonable condition $x(2\pi)>0$  implies $0<B<{1\over2}$. The following figure shows the resulting $\gamma$ when $n=6$, $A=0.2$, and $\>B=0.11$:
[image]

Now we have to transform $\gamma$ into a spring with given endpoints $(x_0,y_0)$, $\>(x_1,y_1)$. Let
$$d:=\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2},\qquad\phi:=\arg(x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0)\ .$$
Then the coordinates of the transformed point $(\bar x,\bar y)$ are obtained from $(x,y)$ by the operation
$$\left[\matrix{\bar x\cr \bar y\cr}\right]=\left[\matrix{x_0\cr y_0\cr}\right]+d\ \left[\matrix{\cos\phi&-\sin\phi \cr \sin\phi&\cos\phi\cr}\right]\>\left[\matrix{x\cr y\cr}\right]\ .$$

Comment: What more can I ask. This is perfect! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

$$\boxed{\huge\arcsin(\sin x)}$$
[image]

### Specific Purpose Equation:

$$(y-y_1)=2\frac A{\pi}\arcsin\left(\sin \left(t\frac {(x-x_1)}{2\pi}\right)\right)$$

Comment: You misinterpreted my question. I am not asking for that. I am asking for the equation of a triangle wave/"helical" wave passing through fixed points. (As written in the question in detail). My question is Mathematics, your answer is Physics.

Comment: @AvZ edited....

Comment: Can you make it pass through to fixed points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ such that they have $t$ turns and lie at the mean position?

Comment: Nicely done, Thanks

Comment: @AvZ would you share us what you got in algodoo?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean to ask.

Comment: @AvZ you used this equation and i was asking for just showing the final product

Comment: Oh, That's gonna take some time. I'll have to complete the program.

Comment: @AvZ GOOD LUCK!!

Answer (score 0):

In parametric form, you could get your spring's shape as a function of $t$ turns and amplitude $A$, about an interval of the $x$-axis:

$$f_{x}(A,t)=A(2t\pi-2\cos(2t\pi))\\
f_{y}(A,t)=A\sin(2t\pi).$$

It would be quite simple to take this curve on an interval of desired length, rotate it, and then map it to the desired line in the plane. Also, if you want the crests to be more spread out or squashed together, just augment the $x$ component accordingly.

Comment: The problem is the rotation. I want to do it mathematically. (Also, I'd prefer a triangle wave but I don't know how to plot that)

Comment: I am not sure how to apply rotation theorem to entire functions...

Comment: @AvZ Mathematically, do your rotations in the complex plane. After taking $(x,y)$ to $(x,yi)$, you have

$$f_{x}(A,t)=A(2t\pi-2cos(2t\pi))\\
f_{y}(A,t)=Asin(2t\pi)i.$$

Because our real component is a linear function of $t$ turns, the length of the spring can be taken as $t$. To rotate, multiply both components by $e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the desired angle in radians.

Translate the endpoints to $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2})$ by taking $(f_{x}(A,0),f_{y}(A,0))$ to $(f_{x}(A,0)+x_{1},f_{y}(A,0)+y_{1}i)$, and $(f_{x}(A,t),f_{y}(A,t))$ to $(f_{x}(A,t)+x_{2},f_{y}(A,t)+y_{2}i)$.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time commenting on this site.